# Como obtener la respuesta al hacer Web Scraping a un sitio

Tags: c#, scraping

Hola estoy intentando hacer web scraping a un sitio que usa autenticacion, primeramente quiero autenticarme en ese sitio, el cual tiene usuario, contraseña, y captcha alfanumerico.

He intentado lo siguiente, pero no he podido obtener la respuesta de la autenticacion si fue OK o si hubo errores. en este caso me falta el captcha, pero al menos queria ver el error, la respuesta que devuelve.

```
var cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url);
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
//set the user agent and accept header values, to simulate a real web browser
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";


//SET AUTOMATIC DECOMPRESSION
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

Console.WriteLine("FIRST RESPONSE");
Console.WriteLine();
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}

request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(url+"/pedregal/Sign.aspx");
//set the cookie container object
request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;
request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.101 Safari/537.36";
request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8";

//set method POST and content type application/x-www-form-urlencoded
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

//SET AUTOMATIC DECOMPRESSION
request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.Deflate | DecompressionMethods.GZip;

//insert your username and password
string data = string.Format("username={0}&password={1}", "username", "password");
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;

using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    dataStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    dataStream.Close();
}

Console.WriteLine("LOGIN RESPONSE");
Console.WriteLine();
using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
{
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```